# Javascript: how to save object with private fields to file?

Tags: javascript, json, object, save, private

I've tries to save an object like a string and for this I use `JSON.stringify()` but it picks up only public fields.

How to grab privates?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function Class1() {
            var prop1 = 1;
            this.prop2 = 2;
        };

        var inst1 = new Class1();

        var str = JSON.stringify(inst1);

        console.log(str);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the output is: {"prop2":2}

and I want {"prop1":1, "prop2":2}

Comment: If they are private, they should not be accessible outside the class context, right?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, true but i still need a way to save entire object data

Comment: In this case I'm afraid that you have to create public methods to get these private properties, then create a new object with public properties populated with those private values.

Comment: thats not private field, thats local variable ... maybe should edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "private property" is not actually found inside your object, it is a variable in the constructor's scope only. If you interact with it via methods, then it will be available to those methods via closures.

If you want to serialize an object with its private properties, you need to write your own serialization and deserialization methods that can access the private properties (via closures) as explained above.

Some code to get you started:

```
function Class1(opt_prop1, opt_prop2) {
  var prop1 = opt_prop1 || 1;
  this.prop2 = opt_prop2 || 2;

  this.toJSON = function() { 
    return { prop1 : prop1, prop2 : this.prop2 }; 
  };
}

Class1.fromJSON = function(str) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);
  return new Class1(obj.prop1, obj.prop2);
}
```

Note that while the `fromJSON` method can be a normal function (which i just happened to make "static" to the Class1 class in the traditional OOP sense by adding it to the constructor), the `toJSON` method needs to access the local variables of the constructor, so it must be defined inside the constructor.

As mentioned by @JamesHill in the comment, if present a [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method can simplify the serialization implementation. You simply need to return a plain object which contains the properties you want serialized (which should be the properties that allow you to restore the instance in the deserialization process).

Comment: Instead of defining `this.serialize` on your class, you could instead define `this.toJSON()`, returning the object you want serialized - the reason for doing this is that JSON.stringify looks for a `toJSON` method on objects first, and uses that to get the representation of the object, if present (sort of like overriding toString in Java)